# How to hide the Contents of a 7-Zip SFX Archive?

Tags: archiving, 7-zip

I've just Created a 7-Zip SFX Archive containing my Test Results. But whenever I open the File.sfx.exe with 7-Zip from the Context menu as Open Archive, I directly get the SFX Contents. I want my users to go through the extraction GUI before getting Access to the file. I'm not speaking of Silent Extraction. Even Tried UPX but of no use. Your help will be solely appretiated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If you are able to extract an archive you are also able to view the contents ...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to have the file extract the data in a way that 7-Zip cannot read.  If 7-Zip can read the data, then 7-Zip can show the contents, because that is what 7-Zip does.

Consider making multiple archives.  One way you can probably achieve your goals is to place an archive within an archive.  Make the inner archive perfectly accessible by 7-Zip, but that won't matter because nobody can see the inner archive until they first crack open your outer archive.

The inner archive can be created with 7-Zip and provide desirable features like compression and keeping track of multiple files.  By using a standard format, you don't need to learn how to implement all of the quirks of a standard format, but you get the benefits provided by the common support of that format.

The outer archive can be some custom format.  If you're a programmer, you can easily create a custom archive format.  Maybe your format simply reverses every 5th bit, which would effectively destroy 7-Zip's ability to make sense of the file.  Then, when someone runs the custom extractor you create, you flip every 5th bit, and run the resulting file (which is the 7-Zip executable).  Your custom extractor can also have a GUI and do whatever else you're seeking to have happen.